# How to convert a template from jade to HBS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, pug, braintree

I am not too familiar with the jade template language, but quite familiar with handle bars.  I need to use hbs because my project is based on hbs.

I have the following the braintree payment for nodejs express, and their view was based on jade.
https://github.com/braintree/braintree_express_example/blob/master/views/checkouts/new.jade

```
    form#payment-form(action="/checkouts", method="post")
      section
        .bt-drop-in-wrapper
          #bt-dropin

        label(for="amount")
          span.input-label Amount
          .input-wrapper.amount-wrapper
            input#amount(name="amount" type="tel" min="1" placeholder="Amount" value="10")

      button.button(type="submit")
        span Test Transaction

  script(src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.27.0.min.js")
  script.
    (function () {
      var checkout = new Demo({
        formID: 'payment-form'
      });

      var token = "#{clientToken}";
      braintree.setup(token, "dropin", {
        container: "bt-dropin"
      });
```

Below is my router

```
router.post('/', parseUrlEnconded, function (request, response) {

  var transaction = request.body;

  gateway.transaction.sale({
    amount: 7,
    paymentMethodNonce: transaction.payment_method_nonce
  }, function (err, result) {

    if (err) throw err;

    if (result.success) {
     [...]
```

I essentially want the payment form to be shown in view, and the `payment_method_nonce` value submitted to the server

Comment: I wanted to reply to @spikyjt, but I lack the reputation. [jade-to-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade-to-handlebars) seems to be brokens so you'll have to manually convert the file and rename it using the [docs](https://handlebarsjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jade-to-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade-to-handlebars), which is a nodejs module to do exactly what you ask.

Comment: @chikitin it would be helpful for everyone here if you explained what didn't work. It did work for me at the time of posting, but as you can see that was a while ago! Looking at the package, it hasn't been updated for 3 years.